# Sort Expression multi header in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have 2 headers in my gridview. I am inserting 2nd header in code behind on `RowCreated` event which will be insert above `<asp:BoundField>` row. I have added `SortExpression` property to each `BoundField`. When I run the application `SorExpression` hyperlink is creating on each `BoundField` not on inserted header (It is logically correct). But I want sortexpression on inserted header row. How can I do that?

below I am explaining steps that I did

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvInitiavtives" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="Grid" 
       RowStyle-Width="30px" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeader" RowStyle-CssClass="GridItem" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridAltItem"  DataKeyNames="InitiativeIdx"  >
      <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessUnit" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" SortExpression='BusinessUnit' />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="IFunction" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" SortExpression='IFunction'/>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="SubFunction" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="NotSet" SortExpression='SubFunction' />         
    .....
```

Code Behind

```
  Private Sub gvInitiavtives_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvInitiavtives.RowCreated
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
            Dim HeaderGrid As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
            Dim HeaderGridRow As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert)

            Dim HeaderCell As New TableHeaderCell()
            HeaderCell.Text = "BU"
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)

            HeaderCell = New TableHeaderCell()
            HeaderCell.Text = "Function"

            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)

            HeaderCell = New TableHeaderCell()
            HeaderCell.Text = "Sub - Function"
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)
    ....
    .... 
       gvInitiavtives.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow)

    End If
End Sub
```

Browser

[image]

HTML

```
   <table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Body_gvInitiavtives" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr class="GridHeader">
                <th>BU</th><th>Function</th><th>Sub - Function</th><th>Initiative Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Cost Center</th><th colspan="2">Estimated Cost Savings</th><th colspan="2">Estimated Personnel Savings</th>
            </tr>
<tr class="GridHeader">
            <th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Body$gvInitiavtives&#39;,&#39;Sort$BusinessUnit&#39;)"></a></th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Body$gvInitiavtives&#39;,&#39;Sort$IFunction&#39;)"></a></th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Body$gvInitiavtives&#39;,&#39;Sort$SubFunction&#39;)"></a></th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">Low</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">High</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">Low</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">High</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridItem" style="width:30px;">
   <td>UNKNOWN</td><td>UNKNOWN</td><td>UNKNOWN</td><td>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I am not interpreting things correctly, but why are you adding new header rows in the RowCreated event? Why not just specify each one as a new BoundField or TemplateField in the front end of your ASPX?

Comment: Okay, let's back up a bit. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to add an image to the header?

Comment: no. I want 2 headers in gridview (it is merged columns) same like it shows in image. and 1sr header row needs to have sortexpression and in 2nd header row (low ,high) columns needs to have sortexpression.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sort expression on header row each column, in which column you not need for sorting then make sort expression empty like

SortExpression=""  -  in which column you not want to apply sorting